# jquery accordion help

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a horizontal accordion on my website, and regardless of what page you on the tab furthest right does not act like the rest, you click the tab and no accordion action happens, I am not sure if this is IE all versions problem or just an IE9 problem, but if someone could spread some light on it that would be great. As I have been looking for bugs for 2 days now and cannot find anything wrong.

[Accordion Link](http://thesmcl.co.uk/our-training)

Comment: what version of IE are you working in? If you click on Harness Training on the page I linked to what do you see? I am running,

IE9 9.0.8112.1642IIC / Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine in IE7 and IE9, IE8 doesn't seem to work at all though for clicking (still cycles through).  FF6 works too.  Haven't checked anythign else.  You sure its not a cache issue?  If you made any recent changes, make sure that you are getting the most up to date files.

EDIT:

IE8 only works when clicking the top portion.  38px high.

Comment: strange in my IE9 it gets to the final option in when cycling and stops cycling.

Answer (score 0):

It worked very well in IE8.

It works quite well in Chrome 13.0.782.215 too.

You've got a great looking site!!! Very well done.